# Wordpress - Plugin H5P - Error 403 when I click on get to install an activity, I get the 403 error message

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403

I get a 403 error with the plugin H5P when I click to install activities.

- I deleted every other plugins
- I suppressed htaccess

The button still doesn't work. The plugin is unusable.

Error in the console :
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()`

When I click on it, I get this message :
`{"success":false,"message":"Un message est nécessaire pour accéder au point de terminaison donné","errorCode":"REQUIRES_POST"}`

(In english : `A message is necessary to get to the given termination point`)

[Error I get when I click on "Installer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX0uc.png)
Also, it's a subsite but I don't see why it could make problems since I used the same plugin on another website without any problems.

If you have any idea how to solve this, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you already checked if for some reason the file system's access permissions have been changed for the wp-content folder and its subfolders where h5p needs to put files to and gets files from (wp-content/uploads/h5p/...)? That's what the HTTP response code 403 can indicate.

Comment: I checked the access permissions on every file related to h5p, from the wp-content to the wp-content/uploads/h5p/... and there are no differences with these same permissions on a website where it works. 755 for uploads, 705 for h5p etc.

Comment: If the H5P folder is set to 705: has it been installed differently, e.g. by copying files instead of installing via the backend of WordPress? Just guessing here, but only the owner has full access, not the group.

Comment: I installed it "normally", clicking on the button to install the extension. I've seen people having the same issue on the official site but no clear solutions have been done.

Comment: Could you possibly share a copy of the contents that the JavaScript dev console is showing when you receive the error? It may contain more hints.

Comment: It's the error I gave on the original message : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () /site/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?token=db38419cef&action=h5p_library-install&id=H5P.InteractiveVideo:1 

I already tried to change the CHMOD permissions but even with permissions to everybody (even those who shouldn't have it) it doesn't work.

Comment: The regular .htaccess file of WordPress doesn't have a rule for that path, but have you checked if there are some restrictions set by the webserver? Could be some RewriteRules that are causing the issue.

Comment: It's the regular .htaccess. Its content is exactly the same than the .htaccess I have on a website where H5P works. At a moment, I was searching how to put the h5p folder on the whitelist of .htaccess but I didn't understood how to do so. I'll search some more and tell you if I find the solution.